# Why I am not able to playback some of the YT videos in my app?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I am developing HTML5 app for TV, which will show YT videos using YouTube IFrame API and `YT.Player` object. But some videos in my app are giving error "Playback on other website has been disabled by the video owner". However, the same video is playing back in YouTube native app on the same TV device. My question - is there anything I should do in my app to playback such videos or only YT app have special ways to playback them?

Comment: You can hide the embed feature on a video in youtube that nobody is allowed to embed it. I would guess that the Youtube native app doesn't need this permission because its youtube themselves and they have other coding and security setups. So there is no official regular way if its not allowed to embed by the creator/uploader of the video.

Comment: For some kinds of videos there is a possibility to get the video not with the embed link for example http://www.youtube.com/embed/iFh1iJzCfZI but it works on the normal url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFh1iJzCfZI in an iframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play Youtube live stream video in application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003127/how-to-play-youtube-live-stream-video-in-application)