# How to play Youtube live stream video in application?

Tags: android, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I am trying to play live stream youtube video in my application using api key but it's showing error like: *`Playback on other applications has been disabled by the video owner.`*

Here is image description:

[image: error image]

Here is my code which is used to load video by using video id:

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    // YouTube player view
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        // Initializing video player with developer key
        youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {

            // loadVideo() will auto play video
            // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
            player.loadVideo("ywrPouTDTAE"); //live vid

            // Hiding player controls
          //  player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the error tell you everything. Did you try with another video and it's the same ?

Comment: I want to load this video only @Ionutj.Bejan

Comment: Looks like the streamer did not allow playbacks of it.. If you know the owner, or it's your video I think you should check on some settings (can't help with this part sorry)

Comment: ok thanks  there is only option to contact owner of this video@ionutj.bejan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Playback on other applications has been disabled by the video owner.

If you get this message, then the uploader of the original YouTube has disabled embedding onto third-party sites like android apps. This is a setting that the original YouTube uploader will need to change.

1. Visit your Video Manager.
2. Find the video you'd like to change and click Edit.
3. Click Advanced Settings under the video.
4. Check the Allow Embedding checkbox under the "Distribution Options" section.
5. Click Save changes at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @HasuSarkar anytime welcome to stack remember to accept the answer if it helped you.  You get reputation points for accepting answers.