# Embed YouTube live stream in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api, live-streaming, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to embed a live stream to android app. This code works perfect for other videos but when I put the URL code of live stream channel it is unable to load. It just keeps on loading. Suggest me something or is there any other API which I need to use for embedding live stream.

```
onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        youTubePlayer.("5kbU-C0FxqA");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }
};
```

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003127/how-to-play-youtube-live-stream-video-in-application) your code should work fine. Have you double-checked the ID you use refers to a valid stream ? Have you checked the stream is not private or anything ?

Comment: Yea, I updated the id and stream is also public stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First video id out-of-date so you need to replace another one and check agein

Also i think your code should be like below

**onCreate**

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
youTubePlayerView.initialize(getString(R.string.google_developer_api_key), this);
```

**OnInitializedListener**

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(""); // your video id 
    youTubePlayer.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make it work with the YouTubePlayer API, you may consider using this alternative player: [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player).

This is all you need to do to play a live video:

Add the player to your XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Initialize the player and play a video:

```
YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
getLifecycle().addObserver(youtubePlayerView);
youtubePlayerView.getPlayerUIController().enableLiveVideoUI(true);

youtubePlayerView.initialize(new YouTubePlayerInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitSuccess(@NonNull final YouTubePlayer initializedYouTubePlayer) {    
        initializedYouTubePlayer.addListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onReady() {
                String videoId = "2ccaHpy5Ewo";
                initializedYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
            }
        });        
    }
}, true);
```

You can see a [working example in the sample app](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/blob/master/core-sample-app/src/main/java/com/pierfrancescosoffritti/aytplayersample/examples/liveVideoExample/LiveVideoActivity.java).