# Playback on other websites has been disabled by the video owner (But it's not)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Please check this video. It's one from my video channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgFXZP8K7Ew

My problem is when I embed this video on my site it shows me this message (https://ibb.co/r3mvsfH). But "Allow Embedding" is checked on the video (https://ibb.co/z6BzGVD). I have two YouTube accounts under the same mail address and all videos from both of them shows "Playback on other websites has been disabled by the video owner"

FYI, It's not live streaming, just the normal video clips from my account.

Tried everything, every troubleshoot; same results.

This is the code I was trying to put

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lgFXZP8K7Ew" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Same problem... exact issue.

Comment: Ever figured out a solution to or the source of this problem? Experiencing the exact same right now.

Comment: @domsson never found the issue. Waited 3 months, got a ton of emails that YouTube is looking into it but they never solved the issue. Later I switched to Vimeo.

Comment: BTW @domsson according to a forum (found on Google search), if you have a number of videos but not a good number of views, YouTube disable some features, and this embed error issue comes after that disabling. I am not sure though about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play Youtube live stream video in application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003127/how-to-play-youtube-live-stream-video-in-application)

Answer (score 1):

This is something that only the video owner can enable. YouTube can not do anything about it. All you have to do is to allow the users to play the video on YouTube itself if this error occurs. For additional information visit: [How to play Youtube live stream video in application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003127/how-to-play-youtube-live-stream-video-in-application)

Answer (score 0):

This problem of "Problem on other websites has been displayed by the video owner" can be corrected if you are the owner of the YouTube video.
Go to the video that shows the error, Go to the video details on the left menu.
Move down to the license part. Below this, you have an option called" Allow Embedding". Click this check box. Now save your video. If you refresh the page now you can see the YouTube video.